# Select dates from table where all entries from my list are in table for that date

Tags: mysql

I am very new to mySQL.  I have a set of items A,B,C with their corresponding dates and prices in my table (db).

```
Name  |   dates   |  Price  |
-----------------------------
A     | 20170101  | 1       |
B     | 20170101  | 2       |
D     | 20170101  | 3       |
A     | 20161201  | 1       |
B     | 20161201  | 1.5     |
C     | 20161201  | 1       |

...
```

I would like to obtain all the distinct dates where there are entries for all 3 items A B and C.  For the subset above, I would like the query to return 20161201 but not 20170101.

I think? the syntax should look something like

```
select distinct d.dates from db d1 join (select dates,group_concat(distinct name) gc from db group by dates) d2 where find_in_set(...
```

but I have no idea how to continue. Im also happy with an entirely different approach

Can someone help please.  Thanks!

Comment: Select date from my_table where name in ('a','b','c') group by date having count([distinct] name) = 3

Comment: And if the distinct *is* required then you have a bigger problem with your table - i.e. no PRIMARY KEY

Comment: This question is asked and answered so often; I'll just leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

---

`SELECT dates 
FROM db WHERE name IN ('A', 'B', 'C') 
GROUP BY dates
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM db db1 WHERE db1.name IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
)`

---